# Can rooting be the cause of battery drainage?

Tags: rooting, battery-life, root-access

Its been three weeks I have `rooted` my phone. I have installed a lot of apps using `link2sd` on external sd card. I have noticed that since the rooting, the battery goes down very fast. 80% of charge goes down to below 40% overnight when on stand-by (without any data/wifi connection). Can the root be cause for that? It hasn't been even a year I bought that phone.

**Note**: I am using `android 2.3.6` and `juicedefender` for improving battery usage.

Comment: "root" itself should not be the cause. However, the *rooting process* might have caused some instabilities. I remember when having rooted my *Milestone 2*, it booted twice a day. A factory reset solved that (and of course kept root itself intact, as the `/system` partition is not affected by a factory reset).

Answer (score 4):

**Short answer:** No

**Long answer:** It's all the apps and services running in the background, some great apps I use for monitoring what's going on with the phone:

- [System Panel](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nextapp.systempanel.r1) [theres also a lite version, [SystemPanelLite Task Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=nextapp.systempanel)]
- [CPU Spy](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bvalosek.cpuspy)
- [BetterBatteryStats](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.asksven.betterbatterystats)

With those you will be able to narrow down what is causing all the battery drain

Also it may be wakelocks on your kernel

Comment: You forgot the link to the 3rd app

Comment: Because I'm new I can only post two links per post =/

Here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.asksven.betterbatterystats&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwyLDEsImNvbS5hc2tzdmVuLmJldHRlcmJhdHRlcnlzdGF0cyJd